# Send Files as parameter in API call in Android

Tags: android, file-upload, android-volley, android-async-http

I usually use volley library for web services and now I want to send the File (i.e. image,video etc) as a parameter just like name,country,age or other parameters. Which is the most suitable ans easy way to achieve that functionality? I've tried with 'android-async-http' but i get deprecation warning at Header in "public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,JSONArray response)" and if I use "useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'" then error shifts to "super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);" line. Following is the code that 'm using. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Code:

```
private void sendRegisterData(String path) {

    String baseUrl = AppGlobal.BaseURL+"register";
    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("name", name_text);
    params.put("country", country_text);
    params.put("userType", userType_text);
    params.put("email", email_text);
    params.put("password", password_text);
    try {
        File file = bmpToFile(profileImage_bmp); //   Convert bmp to File to pass as parameter
        params.put("avatar", file);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Problem updating profile! Try later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        // new SnackBar(this,
        // "Problem updating profile! try later.").show();
        this.finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.post(this, baseUrl, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                              JSONArray response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgress(bytesWritten, totalSize);
            int progressPercentage = (int) ((int) 100 * bytesWritten / totalSize);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                              JSONObject response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            Log.e("RESULT FRIEND LIST JO", response.toString() + "");

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                              String responseString) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseString);
            Log.e("RESULT FRIEND LIST", responseString.toString() + "");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                              Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);

            // Log.e("Upload Exeption", errorResponse.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                              String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onFinish();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });
```